# Breaking a big fetch request into smaller ones

Tags: react-native, server, request, fetch

Here's my fetch request

````js
const url = 'https://mywebsite.com/settings';
const options = {
  headers: {
    dataType: 'json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer csjslkKJFLKDFe3irj2rfklf',
  },
};
    
fetch(url, options)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

When I do this request, I get the following error:

```bash
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
````

I would prefer to not up the max request size of my website.

Is there a way I can set a request limit and have it do multiple requests to grab the data from the file in, say 5MB chunks?

Comment: We don't know, does your backend support that?

Comment: You have to do that in the backend. You can't chunk data fetch from the front-end.